# Print function not working properly with direct string, but works with string passed through variable?

Tags: c, string, x86, kernel, osdev

I'm writing a kernel in C, and I just did some work on a print function. But the issue is that it will print an argument passed as a string in a variable, but not a directly given string.

```c
char str[] = "foo";
print(str);    //works properly
print("bar");  //doesn't print anything
```

I'm guessing that this has to do with the way that the string is set up when put directly into a parameter, but I'm quite new to C. If somebody could please explain this to me, that would be great.

Here's the code for the print function:

```c
int print(char str[]) {
  //scroll if needed
  if (vidpointer > vidmem + 3840) {
    scroll();
    vidpointer -= 160;
  }
  //for each character in the string, write it to video memory, along with color code
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
    vidpointer = writebyte(vidpointer, str[i]);
    vidpointer = writebyte(vidpointer, printcolor);
  }
  //create newline, if printnewl is equal to 1
  if (printnewl == 1) {
    int length = strlen(str);
    while (length > 80) length -= 80;
    vidpointer += 160 - (length * 2);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you link your kernel? Is the data-segment where the compiler puts literal strings included in your linker script? It is usually added to the code segment when linking.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude My current linker command is as follows: `i386-elf-ld -o "Binaries/full_kernel.bin" -Ttext 0x1000 "Binaries/kernel_entry.o" "Binaries/kernel.o" --oformat binary`. I'm not sure exactly how to set it so string literals go to the data segment.

Comment: You need a linker script to set up and include the needed sections. [The OSDev wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page) have good information about it in their examples.

Comment: @JohnSmith Aside: Avoid potentially recalling `strlen()` many times. `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {` --> `for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++) {`. I'd also expect `int print(char str[])` --> `int print(const char str[])`.

Comment: Are you sure you have read enough sectors of your kernel into memory with your bootloader? How big is your binary and how many sectors do you read? It is possible that the string in a read only section may not have been properly read into memory.

Comment: Problems like this are often not related to the C code but things like the bootloader. We really need to see all your code and how you compile/assemble/link the code and build your disk image.

Answer (score 0):

you should reinstall your compiler, I had this problem too

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).